# Dynamically scaling webpage list elements to have 100% width and equal scaling height

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I was learning how to create a table to display searchable data in a list using HTML. I have it split into two columns and want the elements to scale to the screen size. If possible, I wanted to have the width of the element divide the webpage's width in half and have their height scale to the width making the element into a square. What I currently have scaled the width, but my fix overlaps the two columns and creates a few other issues. I also could not figure out how to have the ratio of the height: width is 1:1. Here is the modified w3school code I am working with: 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZRZ717W4LB3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with a bit more trying if anyone else has a similar desire for this layout: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZS3SPUN6GOH.